# What books are shown on the bookshelf in Interstellar?

Tags: interstellar

What books are visible on the bookshelf in *Interstellar*?

I could only focus on *The Stand*, by Stephen King, since it's one of my favorites. But I'd love to see a more complete list.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The most complete list seems to be on a [forum for Christopher Nolan fans](http://www.nolanfans.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=15778).

The main post on that thread has the most recently updated list, as compiled by those forum users. Here’s a copy of the list from the main post:

> So far, the entries are:
>
> - *The Stand* by Stephen King
> - *Winter's Tale* by Mark Helprin
> - *Out of the Blue* by Isabel Wolf
> - *Time's Arrow* by Martin Amis
> - *Maugham: A Biography* by Ted Morgan
> - *Downwinders: An Atomic Tale* by Curtis and Diane Oberhansly
> - *One Hundred Years of Solitude* by Gabriel Garcia Marquez
> - *The Story of Edgar Sawtelle: A Novel (P.S.)* by David Wroblewski
>
> Can you help me add more?
>
> EDIT: Thank you guys for your help so far! Keep them coming! I'll
>   update this post as new info comes through.
>
> - *The Big Nowhere* by James Ellroy
> - *The Willoughbys* by Lois Lowry
> - *Moby Dick* by Herman Melville
> - *The Waste Land* by T.S. Elliot (specifically the poem "Four Quartets")
>
> EDIT 2: Here's WIRED magazine's article on the book case complete with
>   comments from Chris about a few of the books
>   http://www.wired.com/2014/11/interstellar-murphs-library/#x and here
>   is their list:
>
> - *The Wasp Factory* by Iain Banks
> - *Gravity's Rainbow* by Thomas Pynchon
> - *Emma* by Jane Austen (and what he says about this...<3 )
> - *A Wrinkle in Time* by Madeleine L'Engle
> - *Labyrinths* by Jorge Luis Borges
> - *The Go Between* by L.P. Hartley
> - *Flatland: A Romance of Many Dimensions* by Edwin Abbott
>
> A few glimpses of authors/names:
>
> - Janet Finch
> - Diana Gabaldon
>
> Edit 3:
>
> - Wonderstruck by Brian Selznick
>
> I have also created [a Pinterest board](http://www.pinterest.com/magnusrexbegins/murphs-bookcase/) (easiest way I could think of to
>   display).
>
> Edit 4: Here are new additions with the help of BluRay technology!
>
> - *The Glass Castle* by Jeannette Walls
> - *A Life Inspired: Tales of the Peace Corps* by Peace Corps
> - *The Time Machine* by H.G. Wells
> - *Three Cups of Tea* by Relin and Mortenson
> - *The Fatal Shore* by Robert Hughes
> - *The Balloon Man* by Charlotte Armstrong
> - *The Fountainhead* by Ayn Rand
> - *The Devil’s Alternative* by Frederick Forsythe
> - *Rogets Thesaurus*
> - *In a Different Voice: Psychological Theory and Women’s Development* by Carol Gilligan
> - *Little Children* by Tom Perrotta
> - *The Good Earth* by Pearl S. Buck
> - *Gravedigger’s Daughter* by Joyce Carol Oates
> - *Zeitoun* by Dave Eggers
> - *The Reapers* by John Connolly
> - *We were the Mulvaneys* by Joyce Carol Oates (Interesting side note: Nolan cites the painting “Christna’s World” as a key influence on the
>     Farmhouse setting of Interstellar. Early editions of this book use
>     that same painting as a cover.)
> - *Unabridged Dictionary of the English Language*
> - *Wonderstruck* by Brian Selznick
> - *Little Women* by Louisa May Alcott
> - *The Fault in Our Stars* by John Green
> - *The Century* by Peter Jennings and Todd Brewster

There are other guesses or unconfirmed observations in that thread if you’re interested – stuff like authors for whom the title of the book couldn’t be made out, or guesses that weren’t checked. It also includes links to partial lists on other sites. These partial lists tend to be based on what happened to catch somebody’s eye (usually in the cinema, not the DVD) rather than a complete, frame-by-frame list.

But even that long list isn’t complete. [*Yahoo! Movies*](https://www.yahoo.com/movies/interstellar-reading-list-what-books-were-on-the-102013440002.html) spotted a few items which don't appear above:

- *Lindbergh* by A. Scott Berg
- A *Dorothy Parker* collection
- A collection of *Sherlock Holmes* stories
- *The Official Scrabble Players Dictionary*
- *Encyclopedia Britannica*

Comment: Beat me by 3 seconds; great find

Comment: [Here](http://www.nolanfans.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=15778&start=30#p935779) is a link to a later post by the original thread author with some of the books where only the author could be made out, or only partial titles.

Comment: A lot of that is actually an awesome list of books I should eventually read!

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget the textbook (with the pictures that Murph loved, one showing the Horsehead Nebula and another showing the formation of the solar system).

The interior pages are pages 260-263 of Goldsmith and Owen, *The Search for Life in the Universe*.

The (back) cover appears to be invented, with a title "Physical Science: Engineering Space and Time".

Answer (score -1):

the opening titles of the film, as the camera moves to the right I spotted the sequel to Jose Saramago's Blindness" called "Seeing".